# Lightweight zxcvbn alternative?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, passwords

Wondering if there are any lightweight [zxcvbn](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn) alternatives out there. I'm not at the scale where I need my password strength meter to be incredible - rather, I need to keep my asset sizes down.

Does anyone have anything lightweight that could get me say, 80% of the way there - maybe without the entire dictionary in the file (I'm assuming thats where the bulk of the size is coming from)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've come up with thus far is to only load zxcvbn on pages where I need it. Other than that, I haven't found a good solution out of the box. One day maybe I'll roll my own.